# Node JS DataTables And mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I im working with NodeJS and datatables with mysql. I can't get json data response from my server and this is error i get from console.log:

```
/root/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:78
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
          ^
Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty
```

Here is my server.js:

```
 var express      = require('express'),
 var mysql        = require('mysql');
 var async        = require('async'),
     QueryBuilder = require('datatable');
     var tableDefinition = {
     sTableName: 'users'
 };

var queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(tableDefinition);

var requestQuery = {
    iDisplayStart: 0,
    iDisplayLength: 5
};
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({          // CONNECT - MySQL
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'mydatabasepassword',
    database : 'mydatabasename',
 });

connection.connect();

/* RETURN - all users */
apiRoutes.get('/users', function(req, res) {
/* QUERY - user */
connection.query(queries.changeDatabaseOrSchema,function(err){
    if (err) throw err;

        async.parallel({
            recordsFiltered: function(cb) {
                connection.query(queries.recordsFiltered, cb);
            },
            recordsTotal: function(cb) {
                connection.query(queries.recordsTotal, cb);
            },
            select: function(cb) {
                connection.query(queries.select, cb);
            }
        }, function(err, results) {
            if (err) { 
                res.error(err);
            } else {
                res.json(queryBuilder.parseResponse(results));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And users.html file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#users').dataTable({
            'aoColumnDefs': [
                { 'sTitle': 'ID', 'aTargets': [ 0 ], 'sWidth': '1%' },
                { 'sTitle': 'Description', 'aTargets': [ 1 ], 'sWidth': '3%' }
            ],
            'bAutoWidth': false,
            'bServerSide': true,
            'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
            'aaSorting': [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
            'sAjaxDataProp': 'data',
            'sAjaxSource': '/api/users?id=1',
            'oLanguage': {
                'sEmptyTable': 'No users available',
                'sLengthMenu': '_MENU_ users',
                'sInfo': 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ users',
                'sInfoFiltered': '(filtered from _MAX_ total users)',
                'sInfoEmpty': 'Showing 0 to 0 of 0 users',
                'sZeroRecords': 'No matching users found',
                'sSearch': ''
            }
        });
        /* DATATABLES - placeholder */
        $('div.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search').addClass('form-control');
    });
</script>
```

I im using:
       "express": "~4.14.0",
       "mysql": "2.12.0",
       "async": "~2.1.4",
       "underscore": "~1.8.3"

UPDATE:

I try with this code on server.js:

```
/* RETURN - all users */
apiRoutes.get('/users', function(req, res) {
/* QUERY - user */
pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if (err) {
       connection.release();
       res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
       return;
     }
        console.log(queries);
    connection.query(queries.changeDatabaseOrSchema,function(err, row){
        connection.release();
        res.json(queryBuilder.parseResponse(row));

    });
});
});
```

And in console.log in server.js i got this:

```
{ recordsTotal: 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM clients',
  select: 'SELECT * FROM dealers' }
```

And in Chrome JSON return from server.js i got this:

```
{"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0,"draw":0}
```

Anyone have idea how to get valid JSON from server.js so that datatables on chrome works?

Thanks.

Comment: you are using async so no idea about it i think you are sending response in the code which  is going twice i think so....not sure

Comment: thanks...can you give meexample code to use it without async? i take example from here: https://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable i im trying with different appricah but if i get clear to this i im sending no query to mysql so there is error...if someone have working example using nodeJS+datatables+mysql

Comment: try this link https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/node-js-mysql

Comment: I try above link and reading from mysql is ok..no errors at all..i try to get error in console.log and i im getting this: { [Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty]
  code: 'ER_EMPTY_QUERY',
  errno: 1065,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }  So i see that my query that is sending ajax request from users.html is empty...need to find way why is empty

Comment: no idea this will help but you can try to find out there is any query with thiis.         if(isEmptyObject(query)) {
  // There are no queries.
} else {
  // There is at least one query,
  // or at least the query object is not empty.
}

Comment: soory for delay...i was using console.log(requestQuery); and i get every time in console: { iDisplayStart: 0, iDisplayLength: 5 } so if someone could post example code of client side how i could send ajax call to datatables in node js in server side..i get error empty query because in my users.html file (posted code above) does not SEND ajax parameters

Comment: i just fix the problem porting datatables php scripe server side to javascript serverside for datatables with mysql on Node JS and now is all working perfectly..for PHP script of server side see datatables manual on his web page...because this javascript code that reads requests from datatables and run query on mysql is user depended.

Comment: @user2631534 could you please share the nodejs converted code of the php file on datatables site? Thanks